# UIViewAnimation block UIView interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have an UIViewController named `MainViewController`.
It's frame:
I also have an UIView named `SingleSearchView` which is a subview of MainViewController.

And I add this `singleSearchView` to the MainViewController:

```
self.singleSearchView = [[SearchView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -480, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:singleSearchView];
```

**When I'm trying the following animation to "switch" to the `singleSearchView` it blocks me from any touch interaction with the `singleSearchView`**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"searchAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f]; 
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.singleSearchView cache:YES];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];    
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I also tried this way:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];  
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Thanks

Comment: User interaction blocked AFTER the animation is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
CATransition* trans = [CATransition animation];
[trans setType:kCATransitionPush];
[trans setDuration:0.5];
[trans setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];

[self.singleSearchView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

CALayer *layer = self.view.layer;
[layer addAnimation:trans forKey:@"Transition"];
```

Answer (score 3):

From this [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921173/uiview-animations-canceling-any-touch-input):

> Turns out UIView's block animation by default blocks user interaction, and to get around it you need to pass UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction as one of the options. Hopefully someone else will have some use of this information as well.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I've also noticed that on iOS 4, AllowUserInteraction is off by default. On iOS 5, it's ON by default.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to move self.view. The self.view property is special in the UIVIewControll hierarchy. You should create a subview and animate this one instead...

Comment: Thanks, but I want to make like a "Push" animation the the singleSearchView "pushes" from top the MainViewController view downside the screen