# How to avoid an animation to disable touch interaction (scroll, swipe, etc)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im trying to make an animation over a view in my ViewController.

My problem is that the scroll/swipe gestures over other elements like UITableViewControllers or UIPageViewControllers get disabled until the animation finishes.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921173/uiview-animations-canceling-any-touch-input?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your animations using `allowUserInteraction` option:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction,
       animations: {
           // Your animations here
       },
                completion: nil
)
```